# How to palindromize a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, element

> ```
> palindromize :: [a] -> [a]
> palindromize [] = []
> palindromize [x] = [x]
> palindromize (x:xs) = (x:xs) ++ reverse(x:xs)
> ```

I did this code in haskell but in the middle element I don't want to see double, how to do this ?
(Another way I don't want to see the original list last element)
Shall I use head or tail or something?

Like that:
palindromize "mad"  == "madam"
palindromize "race" == "racecar"

Comment: What should `palindromize "racecar"` do? What about `palindromize "raceca"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use [**`tail :: [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:tail) to obtain a list that contains all elements of the list, except the first one. In fact a list in Haskell is defined conceptually as a linked list, and `tail` can thus be seen as a "getter" of the tail of a linked list node.

We know that if we reverse a non-empty list, that such list contains at least one element, so we know such `tail` exists. We thus call `tail` on the result of the `reverse`:

```
palindromize :: [a] -> [a]
palindromize [] = []
palindromize xs = xs ++ tail (reverse xs)
```

We can also make use of [**`drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:drop), by calling `drop 1`, we extract a list without the first element, but `drop 1` is more safe: for an empty list `drop 1` will return the empty list. If we use `drop 1`, we can also get rid of the different clauses: a palindrome of a list is then the list and the reverse of the list where we dropped the first element from:

```
palindromize :: [a] -> [a]
palindromize l = l ++ drop 1 (reverse l)
```

Comment: Just a quick note that the `[x]` case is redundant, since the `xs` case will add an empty list to end when the list contains a single element.